# Persisting data across SuiteScript 2.0 map/reduce stages

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am continually beating my head up against this desired feature, but I can't seem to find it in any of the NS2.x documentation.

I would like to persist script-runtime data across the multiple stages in the map/reduce architecture.  For example: start time of getInputData stage, number of records processed, configuration data, etc.

However, all features seem to be designed to prevent this.  Much of it (such as the configuration data) I've put into cache storage (via N/cache interface), but this comes with problems such as cache persisting across instances of the script running that will use an outdated or other-deployment configuration.  I've had to create a per-session key of date/timestamp+user to keep things unique where necessary.

There is a Session object off of the N/runtime module, but this blanks itself out between stages, so it does not run on a true execution instance scope-- which is what I would expect a "session" to be.  I have verified this with Debug trace that show the Session object to be non-blank at end of getInputData() stage, but completely empty when reaching the summary() stage.  Even writing to the summaryContext does not seem useful or helpful, as only brief summary data can be written there.

Any help (or pointing to an already-answered question) would be useful; I can't seem to find this discussed anywhere on NetSuite help forums or on StackOverflow at all.

Comment: I should point out that cache data can only hold repeatable data creation as part of its content.  This means that most of it will be based on record searches or data derived from those, not on stage-scope based information such as timestamps or record counts.  That is why cache can't be used for all information, as it might be dropped and need to be recreated on demand by the script.

Comment: I faced almost the same problem, and my advise is : you need to stop thinking about the notion "persisting" because like you said it is probably impossible. This doesn't mean you can't find a solution for your problem, you just must start thinking how to use the available options to solve it : It is what I always do, and it works. If you want, just update the question to explain what you want to do, and we can help suggesting the right architecture.

Comment: It turns out that most of the data that I am looking for is already in the summaryContext object.  By "chance" as it were.

Comment: But it is only impossible because of some blindness to this use case on Oracle's part.  Because of this missing feature, I have had to compensate by: 1)  Having the initiating Suitelet create a unique key for later grouping and pass that as a parameter; 2) Passing some undesirably complicated structures between the map() and reduce() stages; and 3) Dropping some field-related functionality usage between stages because record objects are collapsed to JavaScript objects

Comment: Yeah I understand your frustration, I have been there too, but to be fair (playing the Devil's advocate :) ) : 1. It is not an oracle problem, Map/Reduce was there before Netsuite was acquired by Oracle. 2. I think this related to the fact that Map/Reduce stages are designed to be Run in parallel (in case you have mutiprocessor in your Netsuite account) : so passing some data between Maps/Reduces can be tricky + the fact that if one process fails, it doesn't affect the other ones and it will re-run automatically... so it is kind of an obligation to completely separate those "executions".

Comment: My main problem has been with "session-only" data, that is unique for this run of all stages on a single map/reduce invocation.  This would contain setup data such as arbitrary unique identifiers to tie session actions together, or data that is intensive to rebuild.  There is no reason this couldn't be set up in getConfigData() and be available to all other stages; they are already persisting config.write() activity and a lot of other objects.  I agree it doesn't make sense to write to in parallel map() or reduce() stages though; I really just want a read function on it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not store what you want on a document using the N/file? I mean it's expensive, but should work without any conflicts.

Comment: That would require the file to be read in each map() and reduce() call, not a help in my case.  I am switching to SS 2.x to improve performance available through concurrency, and reading a file just slows things down as it would happen on every record process.